# Are there any items that give you an extra attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, equipment

Are there any items that give you an extra attack?

Comment: Strongly suggest that you take the time to at least search for a few keywords on D&D Beyond or google before you ask a question that amounts to "look through the book for me".  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No need to delete. (Nor ability to, as it has upvoted answers.) It's not an amazing question, but it's not off-topic or unsuitable, either.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to explain my questions more in the future.

Comment: The big thing that's lacking here is whether you mean duplicating the Extra Attack class feature (make two attacks instead of one when taking the attack action), or any features that let you consistently make more attacks per round or on your turn, e.g. by also spending a bonus action.  It's fine if you're interested in any/all of these possibilities, but it would be a better question if it made some effort to think of possibilities and mention them.  (Partly this is a matter of demonstrating some effort on your part, but also disambiguating whether you literally mean the Extra Attack feature)

Comment: You can find useful help on how to formulate questions in the help center, for example [How to ask good questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Merely repeating the question text in the body just feels like you did not put any effort into it.

Comment: I think it's a worthy question, because "getting an extra attack" is hard to Search for, since it can be accomplished in many ways, and in many different phrasings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Scimitar of speed seems like exactly what you're looking for.

The scimitar of speed from the Dungeon Master's Guide and the Basic Rules grants you an extra attack":

> you can make one attack with it as a bonus action on each of your
> turns.

The wording of this magic item does not require that you take the attack action or attack with the weapon on your turn, it simply grants you a bonus action attack with the weapon.

### A potion of speed, or any magic item that allows you to cast Haste

The text of the Haste spell reads

> ...and it gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can
> be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash,
> Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

So a magic item granting a Haste effect will grant you an extra attack so long as the spell stays in effect.

Another magic item that can grant the Haste spell is the artifact Blackrazor:

> Blackrazor can cast the Haste spell on you once per day. It decides
> when to cast the spell and maintains concentration on it so that you
> don't have to.

Since you don't have to concentrate on the spell yourself, the potential downsides are limited as you don't risk breaking concentration, Blackrazor does however add the downside of potentially devouring your soul.

### The Illusionist's Bracers can give you extra castings of attack cantrips

The Illusionist's Bracers from Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica reads as follows:

> ...whenever you cast a cantrip, you can use a bonus action on the same
> turn to cast that cantrip a second time.

Using this, you could be granted an extra attack of a cantrip such as Booming Blade, Green Flame Blade, or any cantrip that requires an attack roll.

Beyond this, there aren't many magic items that grant extra attacks.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic Thank you, I'll include this

Comment: @Exempt-Medic The question asks for magical items, and a double bladed scimitar is a mundane weapon with the special property

Comment: I would be fine with mundane items too. I will change the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

The *Scimitar of Speed* lets you make an extra attack with it as a bonus action.

The *potion of speed* grants you the effects of a *haste* spell, including the ability to take an extra Attack action each turn. (Likewise, any other item that could *haste* you, like a *ring of spell storing*, would do the trick.)

Illusionist's Bracers and the Double-Bladed Scimitar, from Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica and Eberron: Rising from the Last War, respectively, can also increment your ability to make attacks. Those books are outside the "core", though, so there's no assuming a GM is necessarily aware of them, never mind that they'd allow them.

Answer (score 1):

### Scimitar of speed

[This](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/scimitar-of-speed) weapon allows you to make an extra attack with it as a bonus action.